# Cannot get Pathogen to work in Vim

Tags: vim, plugins, pathogen

I know there are multiple posts on this question but I have tried with no avail to get this simple part of Vim to work. I would like to get the pathogen plugin to work with Vim.  As a few points, I am working on a Windows system.  I have downloaded pathogen via github and have created the directories `.vim` and subdirectories `autoload` and `bundle`.  My `.vimrc` is the default created with `mkvimrc` with:

```
call pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

added to the bottom.  Addressing other postings I have seen:

```
:set cp? = nocompatible
```

One area I am guessing is part of the issue is after I run `:scriptnames` I don't get the `.vim` directory. I only get the `Vim\.vimrc` and `vim73` directories.  How do I address this?  I have been at this a long time and apologize if this is obvious to others here.

Comment: BTW, your `:set` syntax is wrong. There must be no spaces around the `=`, and drop the `?`; it is for showing the current value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Windows the default location of the local user configuration is `$HOME/vimfiles`. If your files are in `$HOME/.vim` then you either need to move them to `vimfiles` or add `.vim` to your runtimepath in your .vimrc:

```
set runtimepath+=~/.vim
```

Also, if Pathogen is in a subdirectory of `bundle` you will need to run it explicitly from there, since by default Vim will only look in `~/.vim/`. Put this in your `.vimrc` before the `pathogen#infect` call:

```
runtime bundle/pathogen/autoload/pathogen.vim
```

Comment: That was exactly it, I moved the .vim directory into vimfiles and all seems to be working.  Thank you, this has been driving me nuts.

Comment: No problem. This often confuses me when moving files between different platforms. I wish Vim's defaults were consistent!

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was re-downloading the `pathogen.vim` as it had somehow failed to download by failing to follow a redirect. The URL specified on tpope's [github](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) has the following step:

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle && \
curl -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://tpo.pe/pathogen.vim
```

You will know the redirect failed to download as the contents of `pathogen.vim` will be a 302 redirect page. Just download from the URL contained in the redirect e.g:

```
wget -N -O ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/master/autoload/pathogen.vim
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Vim with **disabled plugins** and type `:set rtp` - notice that:

- if you are on Unix, then by default: the first goes `~/.vim` and the last goes `~/.vim/after`;
- if you are on Windows, then by default: the first goes `~/vimfiles` and the last goes `~/vimfiles/after`.

This is sort of Vim convention. `after` directories are used to forcefully override Vim's defaults or plugins' settings, which is important sometimes. That's why they are the last in the `rtp`.

Pathogen actually parses the structure of your current `rtp` variable and uses it to inject paths of plugins into the `rtp` properly. For example, look at my `rtp`:

```
runtimepath=
~/.vim,
~\.vim\plugins\NERDCommenter,
~\.vim\plugins\NERDTree,
~\.vim\plugins\SameSyntaxMotion,
~\.vim\plugins\Tabular,
~\.vim\plugins\UltiSnips,
~\.vim\plugins\c.vim,
~\.vim\plugins\clang_complete,
~\.vim\plugins\CountJump,
~\.vim\plugins\delimitMate,
~\.vim\plugins\fswitch,
~\.vim\plugins\matchit,
~\.vim\plugins\matlab,
~\.vim\plugins\neocomplcache,
~\.vim\plugins\protodef,
~\.vim\plugins\python-syntax,
~\.vim\plugins\solarized,
~\.vim\plugins\syntastic,
~\.vim\plugins\vim-creole,
~\.vim\plugins\vim-latex,
~\.vim\plugins\vim-markdown,
~\.vim\plugins\vim-python-pep8-indent,
~/vimfiles,
D:\Applications\Vim/vimfiles,
D:\Applications\Vim,
D:\Applications\Vim/vimfiles/after,
~/vimfiles/after,
~\.vim\plugins\Tabular\after,
~\.vim\plugins\UltiSnips\after,
~\.vim\plugins\vim-markdown\after,
~/.vim/after
```

Notice how pathogen injected paths. It has detected that several plugins have `after` directory and put them right before `~/.vim/after` - so that the last word is always mine.

To achieve this pathogen needs a pair of either `~/.vim` and `~/.vim/after` or `~/vimfiles` and `~/vimfiles/after` or even `~/stuff` and `~/stuff/after` (not sure about the last case though) as anchors to inject plugins' paths in the right order.

If any directory from this pair is missing, then you will have some nasty experience with pathogen (as I did sometime ago, until I found out all the aforementioned stuff and skimmed through pathogen source code) - because paths will not be able to be injected correctly.

Now you can see that the answer provided by `Prince Goulash` is completely **wrong**:

1. the first mistake is that he has appended `~/.vim` to `rtp` whereas
   he should have prepended it;
2. the second mistake is that he didn't append `~/.vim/after`.

The correct solution looks as follows. If you have to work on different platforms including Windows you should rather add this into your `.vimrc` (I keep this in mine as well - you can infer it from my `rtp` example):

```
if has('win32') || has('win64')
  set runtimepath^=~/.vim
  set runtimepath+=~/.vim/after
endif
```

This snippet will ensure consistency across platforms. You can now use Unix-like directory `.vim` even in Windows and forget about the `vimfiles` crap - which is IMO ugly and awful.

After that you call:

```
call pathogen#infect('plugins') " or wherever your plugins reside
call pathogen#helptags()        " optional, but really cool
```

**NOTE:** `'plugins'` denotes the `~/.vim/plugins` directory, so it is relative of `~/.vim`.